# How to copy Magento 2 extensions to fresh installation

Tags: magento2, extensions

Newbie here. Is there a way I can copy, transfer and redeploy **Magento 2 extensions** to a new **Magento 2** setup? Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your extension code from this (old location)

```
/app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName
```

or this

```
/vendor/CompanyName/ModuleName
```

wherever it is located, into new installation at same location as above.

Then run

```
php magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Please simply Copy your extension and Paste into `magento_root_folder/app/code/`.

Also Run Below Command to Setup Your Extension.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: Magento 2 install extension using COMMAND LINE (Recommended)

Your Magento 2 extensions can be installed in a few minutes by going through these following steps

Step 1: Download/purchase the extension

Step 2: Unzip the file into a temporary directory

Step 3: Upload it to your Magento installation root directory

Step 4: Disable the cache under System­ >> Cache Management

Step 5: Enter the following at the command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Option 2** : add an extension's package to the root composer.json

```
then run composer update

then run php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Option 3 : You can also install extension from admin panel component manager as well , for more details please refer this link - https://magefan.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-extension-2/

Answer (score 0):

Copy the content of your extension from

```
root_folder_of_Old_Magento/app
```

It includes your **design** content of the extension & **code (module)** part of your extension

& paste it at

```
root_folder_of_New_Magento/app
```

If your extension contains any static part than copy **`pub`** folder of your **Old_Magento** & paste it to the **New_Magento**

run the following commands to your Magento

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```